# Two way binding an array of strings in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of strings, and I want each of the strings to be bound to an input.

However, editing the input doesn't seem to update the array (isolated scope issues maybe?).

Suggestions?

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.fruits = ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Banana', 'Strawberry'];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <div style="margin: 20px 0" ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
      <input type="text" ng-model="fruit" />
    </div>

    Fruits: {{fruits}}

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need the array reference which you can get from `$index`. Note however that this won't work if any filtering is done on the `ng-repeat` as the indexing then is based on filtered array not the original

```
<div style="margin: 20px 0" ng-repeat="fruit in fruits track by $index">
      <input type="text" ng-model="fruits[$index]" />
</div>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/OzhodxJudgCW05KZQHrj?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: so, does this mean that fruit is a copy and not the actual array element in the OP's syntax ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 it's the element of the array but it's assigned in a child scope and since primitives don't have inheritance then yes it could be considered a *"copy"*

Comment: @gaurav5430 think of it like `var a=[1,2,3]; b=a[0];//1` then do `b=99` doesn't change array `a`

Comment: i tried your code, i am not sure why but everytime i type a single letter, the focus is lost from the input and i have to bring focus again for typing another letter.

Comment: @gaurav5430 yes... I forgot to put in `track by` . try demo link, works fine

Comment: why do we need track by?

Comment: because it is array of primitives. Otherwise will track by values and that causes focus issues as well as will throw error on duplicates

Comment: also from docs `If you don't have a unique identifier, track by $index can also provide a performance boost`

Comment: i got your point about duplicates, but not about focus issues , any references ?

Comment: no references... just from noted behavior. What is actually happening I think is the elements get repainted and that cause focus loss

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so it seems to me like a case of

> 'ng-model requires a dot in the model name to work correctly with the
>   scope, otherwise it would create a local scope'

What i would suggest is to change your data structure from plain strings to objects containing the strings as a property, something like :

```
 $scope.fruits = [
    {'title':'Apple'},
    {'title':'Mango'},
    {'title':'Banana'},
    {'title':'Strawberry'},
    ];
```

Now, when you bind it to ng-model like this

```
<div style="margin: 20px 0" ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
      <input type="text" ng-model="fruit.title" />
</div>
```

then it will not create any local/child scope, instead it would be able to bind to the `title` property on the items in the `fruits` array.

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/24008/

Comment: sure if items are objects but for array you don't have to restructure and create objects. The idea behind using `dot` is to have an object in `ng-model` but an array is also an object. The whole issue is about prototypal inheritance and array and object literal both have inheritance

Comment: alternate way to look at it is `ng-model="fruit['title']"` and syntax is the same as using array ... `[]` is equivalent to dot